# $cond is not allowed in this atlas tier

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have to perform a search only when a condition is satisfied in the aggregate pipeline in mongoose

```
 const products = await this.product.aggregate([
      {"$cond":[request.query.search!=undefined,
        { $match: { $text: { $search: request.query.search } } }
      ]},
      //other aggregate operators
]);
```

Currently, it's saying $cond is not allowed in this atlas tier But I have to di it only in the aggregate pipeline. Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: The syntax of this looks a little wrong `request.query.search!=undefined` does this work locally?

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in [MongoDb docuemnt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/), `$cond` have to use inside something like `$project`.